# Why can't I select an item in a ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a `ListView` control with a data source from MS Access, now I want to select an item from the ListView and the data will display in a TextBox etc.

How can I select an item in the ListView?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it out...Please change your data provider names and connection string properties

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PId" OnSelectedIndexChanging="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Select
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Product ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Product Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Unit Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("ProductID")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("ProductName")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("UnitPrice")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="SelectLinkButton" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" runat="server"
                        ForeColor="White" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("PId")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("PName")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Price")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="MessageLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

//Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
          BindData();
       }
   }
   private void BindData()
   {
    string constr = "Data Source=Your Server;Database=Your DB;uid=User Name; pwd=Your Password;";
    string query = "SELECT PId, PName,Price FROM tblProducts";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, constr);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(table);

    ListView1.DataSource = table;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}

 protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
 {
    ListView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    string pid = ListView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString(); 
    MessageLabel.Text = "Selected Product ID: " + pid;
    BindData();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing. Are you asking how to call a method when a list item is selected?

There should be plenty of answers after googling, but here is a simple example:

ASP.NET ListBox with OnSelectedIndexChanged:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lbListBox" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbListBox_OnIndexChanged"/>
```

ASP.NET TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
```

Method called in CodeBehind.cs:

```
protected void lbListBox_OnIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listBoxText = lbListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    tbTextBox.Text = listBoxText;
}
```

Comment: in LIST VIEW , i can't select an item... the mouse pointer is a TEXT SELECT when i positioning it to list view not list box sir.

Comment: In that case, I would add an extra LinkButton to your ListView: `<td><asp:LinkButton Text="Click" ID="lkbCallMethod" OnClick="lkbCallMethod_Click" runat="server" /></td>`

And add a new method to your CodeBehind:
`protected void lkbCallMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
      /*TODO*/
}`